# Ada generics at run-time

Tags: generics, runtime, stack, ada

How would you instantiate  a generic at runtime instead of at compile time. Example without using new.

Comment: NOTE: New when instantiating a generic is subtly different from new when allocating memory to a pointer. Is this why you dont want to use it ?

Comment: Can you clarify the question?  My (current) understanding is that all instantiations (logically) take place at run time -- but the code expansion of a generic template always takes place at compile time.  What exactly are you trying to accomplish, and why do you care about avoiding the `new` keyword?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this without use of `new` . You can do it in any declarative section, however that generic will only be extant for the duration of the scope of that declaritive section.

for example (not compiled ada-like pseudocode):

```
get(length)
declare
   package stack is new stack_generic (max_stack_size => length);
begin
   stack.push();
   ...
end;
-- stack package no longer in scope.
```

Does this help ?

Comment: Yes this helps a ton, i think the way the assignment was described was confusing. the whole thing about not using new was confusing.

Comment: No Problem :) also, if this is homework, you can add a homework tag to your Question :)

Comment: Ahh ok will do didnt even think about the hw tag. So from my understanding this would allocate the stack in the system stack instead of the heap correct?

Comment: Stack. (i think!), but any dynamic declarations within stack_generic would be on the heap. see http://www.maxi-pedia.com/what+is+heap+and+stack

Comment: I just talked to my teacher and it is allocated into the stack instead of the heap when doing it this way. So when you're out of the begin-end of the declare block the memory is deallocated and the stack is back to what it was before you declared anything. :D I've spent hours trying to figure this out and it makes so much sense now.Thank you very much!!

Comment: If this was the correct answer you can accept it ;) (Click on the tick!)