# When does generic instantiation occur (i.e., what does the word mean)?

Tags: generics, ada

This question is based on a discussion (now deleted) in response to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9630086/827263).  It's more about terminology than actual programming semantics.

What exactly is generic "instantiation"?  Does it occur at compile time or at run time?

I'll refer to the [latest draft](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/RM.pdf) of the Ada 2012 standard.

The meaning of the term *generic_instantiation* is clear; it's a syntactic construct, something like

```
package Inst is new Generic_Package(This => That);
```

My question is about the verb "instantiate".

I've always thought of "instantiation" as something that occurs at compile time.  It's the expansion of a generic template, and it occurs when the compiler encounters a *generic_instantiation* in a compilation unit.

But other sources refer to "instantiation" taking place, at least optionally, at run time.

[This Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_programming#Generics_in_Ada) says:

> To *instantiate* a generic unit, the programmer passes *actual*
>   parameters for each formal. The generic instance then behaves just
>   like any other unit. It is possible to instantiate generic units at
>   run-time, for example inside a loop.

which seems to imply that instantiation can occur either at compile time or at run time.  I think this is referring to the *elaboration* of the *generic_instantiation*, which does occur at run time -- but then, all elaboration occurs at run time, yes?

I found it surprisingly difficult to get a definitive answer to this from the Ada RM.  There is no glossary entry (Annex N) for "instantiation" or "instantiate".

The closest I could find was this statement in 12.2 (Generic Bodies) paragraph 2, under "Dynamic Semantics":

> The elaboration of a generic body has no other effect than to
>   establish that the generic unit can from then on be instantiated
>   without failing the Elaboration_Check.

which *indirectly* implies that instantiation is a run-time event.

Does the verb "instantiate" properly refer to a compile-time event (expanding a generic template)?  To a run-time event (elaborating a *generic_instantiation*)?  If the latter, what do we call the former?  Is the Ada RM as clear as it needs to be on this point?

Comment: Seems to me, just based on English, instantiation means creation of an instance, which certainly sounds like run-time.

Comment: @DonRoby: Ah, but what is an "instance"?  If an instance is the *code* that results from expanding the template, then it's compile-time.

Comment: @DonRoby: A loose analogy: C macro expansion definitely takes place at compile time, not run time.  Ada generics obviously aren't the same thing, but some of the same principles apply.

Comment: For me the difference between instantiation and elaboration is that a 'normal' unit will have only one possible elaboration, however a generic unit can have more than one instantiation, thereby resulting in more than one elaboration. As such i would postulate that it can happen at either compile time or runtime. (hence the ambiguity present, and the need for this question)

Comment: @NWS: Hmm?  You can declare a package inside a loop, and it will be elaborated on each iteration.  For example: https://gist.github.com/2009420

Comment: Agreed, but it has only 1 possible elaboration! Your example has the same elaboration regardless of its place in code, but a generic is dynamic, and could have a different instantiation/elaboration in each iteration of the loop. EDIT: Referring to a variable in the enclosing scope does not imply a unique elaboration in my book.

Comment: @NWS: I don't understand.  `Pkg` is elaborated 3 distinct times during the execution of the program.  In what sense are those 3 elaborations (3 distinct run-time actions with visibly different behavior) "the same elaboration"?

Comment: Variable 'I' is not part of the package, it is simply referred to within the package. And yes you could assign it to a local variable during elaboration, and thence change behaviour of other methods, but this would be a poor mans version of a generic by using globals (or at least enclosing scope) instead of passing it as a parameter!

Comment: I Suggest we wait for other Ada people to enlighten us as i suspect we are devolving into a discussion we have already had ...

Comment: Maybe on CLA you could get an answer faster..

Answer (score 1):

According to [the generic instantiation](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05rm/html/RM-12-3.html) in the *Static Semantics* part in the rules 12, 13 and 14, it seems to be done at compile time.

But [the Gnat documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.2.4/gnat_ugn_unw/Checking-the-Elaboration-Order-in-Ada-95.html#Checking-the-Elaboration-Order-in-Ada-95), in its *elaboration order control* part, describe that a *Program Error* would be raised under certain circumstances. Such exception is only thrown when running the program.

So the point is, as far as I understood, that at compile time, the compiler checks that arguments support operations and ranges pushed by your generic but that real code is done at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

"Instantiation" is the act of creating an instance of a type (either an object or a derived type).  It also can refer to the creation of an instance of a package or subprogram when speaking of generics.  The instance of a type is an object of that type:

```
type My_Type is
   record
      Range_Begin : Natural := 1;
      Range_End   : Natural := 15_000_000;
   end record;

type My_Type_Access is access all My_Type;

My_Object1 : My_Type_Access := new My_Type;  -- instantiation of My_Type 
                                             -- to create My_Object1

My_Array_Objects : array (Positive range 1 .. 250_000) of My_Type_Access :=
   (others => new My_Type);  -- creates an array of objects of My_Type
```

---

"Elaboration" is the process of preparing a construct such as a package or task for loading and execution.  Haven't studied this recently, however.

Comment: I've seen the word "instantiation" used to refer to creating an instance (object) of a type, but that's not what I was talking about; in Ada, the term almost always refers to *generic* instantiation.  Saying that it "can refer to the creation of an instance of a package or subprogram when speaking of generics" doesn't really answer the question; it doesn't address whether that *creation* occurs at compile time or run time.

Comment: Yes.  You are quite right.  Generic instantiation can occur within any specification -- the declarative portion of a package, subprogram, or task.

A generic can be instantiated in the specification of another generic, in which case it takes effect upon its parent's instantiation.

Elaboration of a specification, for any construct, at run-time can cause an instantiation to occur -- just as the creation of a constant or initialized variable can occur during elaboration.  And yes, this can occur within a loop as NWS indicated.