# Ada Generics: Stack vs Heap Clarification

Tags: generics, heap-memory, instantiation, ada, stack-memory

So I have an assignment that says:

**Please use generic instantiations of packages/classes.  Space for each BMR (matrix) must be allocated in the system stack within the generic package/template, probably during generic instantiation!  You specifically may not use "new,” “malloc,” or any other operator, which allocates space in the heap at runtime in any language.  Clearly mark this section of your code with a highlighter!  You must read all transactions and print all results within the generic package/template.  The I/O routines must be passed as generic parameters**

And unrelated code:

```
generic
    type subscript is (<>);     --range variable to be instantiated
    type myType is private;     --type variable to be intantiated
package genericArray is
    type userDefinedArray is array(subscript range <>) of myType;
end genericArray;
```

---

```
with ada.text_io;  use ada.text_io;
with genericArray;

procedure useGenericArray is
type month_name is (jan, feb, mar, apr, may, jun,
                    jul, aug, sep, oct, nov, dec);
type date is 
    record
        day: integer range 1..31;  month: month_name;  year: integer;
    end record;

type family is (mother, father, child1, child2, child3, child4);

package month_name_io is new ada.text_io.enumeration_io(month_name);
use month_name_io;

package IIO is new ada.text_io.integer_io(integer);
use IIO;

package createShotArrayType is new genericArray(family, date);
use createShotArrayType;

vaccine: userDefinedArray(family);

begin
    vaccine(child2).month := jan;
    vaccine(child2).day := 22;
    vaccine(child2).year := 1986;
    put("child2:    ");
    put(vaccine(child2).month);
    put(vaccine(child2).day);
    put(vaccine(child2).year);  new_line;
end useGenericArray;
```

Again, the code posted has nothing to do with the assignment, but my question is that, in the code posted, is space being allocated in the stack or the heap every time I use the word "new". Because my directions say NOT to use this word, but then it says to use generic instantiation which requires it I think. I would appreciate clarification!

Comment: I wonder whether you are taking the same class that let to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9630086/ada-generics-at-run-time)? If either of these questions is to be closed as a duplicate I think it should be the other one!

Comment: I think you are right. From what I know, all of the directions for future assignments are as poorly written as this. Good thing I found this site. @Simon Wright

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The instructions say

> You specifically may not use "new,” “malloc,” or any other operator, which allocates space in the heap at runtime in any language.

which clearly means you mustn’t do heap allocations (why they couldn’t say that first I don’t know; might have been clearer). And that comma after "operator" is misleading.

Instantiating a generic typically happens at compile time; but even if you did

```
Ada.Integer_IO.Get (N);
declare
   package Inst is new Some_Generic (N);
begin
   ...
end;
```

the instantiation doesn’t of itself involve heap allocation.

You could write the generic so that the instantiation above allocates stack:

```
generic
   J : Positive;
package Some_Generic is
   type Arr is array (1 .. J) of Integer;
   A : Arr;    --  in a declare block, this ends up on the stack
end Some_Generic;
```

or even heap:

```
generic
   J : Positive;
package Some_Generic is
   type Arr is array (1 .. J) of Integer;
   type Arr_P is access Arr;
   P : Arr_P := new Arr;  --  always on the heap
end Some_Generic;
```

but that’s because of the code you wrote in the generic, not the syntax that requires you to use the word `new` to instantiate it.

Comment: so instantiating a generic allocates in the stack? okay, so what would an example look like of allocating something in the heap?

Comment: I’ve added a couple of examples of generics that would involve allocation when instantiated, hope that helps

Comment: ah, so correct me if I'm wrong: 1) the way I posted in the question DOES allocate in the stack. 2) in order to allocate in the heap, I would need to use the word "new" within the generic like you did with the array. Thanks for your time btw!

Comment: Your `genericArray` doesn’t declare any data objects of its own, only a type, so `package createShotArrayType` probably doesn’t allocate anything. The object `vaccine` will be created on the stack. (I’m not quite sure what the original question meant by "*system* stack").

Comment: me neither man, all I know is is that this guy hates data on the heap, and he will take off 10+ points anytime it is allocated there, so I'm just paranoid, thanks for your time!